# Email during domain transfer

Tags: domains, email, domain-registration

My company currently has their domain registered with one company and webhosting with another and they want to move the domain to the same company as the web hosting. It is understood that it will take some time before it has moved.

Unfortunately, the mail server is linked to the domain and I have been told that during the transfer (max 7 days) incoming email is not possible. Two situations are possible, some email is delayed and some email may not arrive at all when the domain is transferred. This is unacceptable for my company.

Is what I have been told true? And is there any work around like temporarily forwarding email sent to the domain to a another address?

Answer (score 1):

Domain transfers do typically take quite a while, and can take even longer than 7 days if the domain administrative contact does not click on a authorization link in their email to approve the transfer.

However, typically, email hosting/mail servers are not "tied" to a domain *registration*. You should be able to transfer your domain to another domain registrar without any loss of email, as long as the name servers that your domain point to will continue to run during (and after) the domain transfer. Name servers are not strictly tied to your registrar. You can check your domain's name servers by doing a [WHOIS lookup](https://www.whois.net/) on your domain.

If, during or right after the domain transfer, your name servers will be shut off by your current registrar, you could change the domain's name servers *before* you initiate the transfer. That way, during the domain transfer, mail will still be able to be delivered. There are many 3rd party DNS providers that would be willing to help you with this.

If you then also need to transfer your email hosting, this should be able to be done without interruption of email service as well.

Answer (score 0):

I usually transfer MX entries during the weekdays. For example, friday afternoon when everybody goes home I change MX entries, and by the monday, it's all good.

That's true what you've been told.